# Azure App Service Bicep template with deployment slot

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

Here is my bicep template to deploy App service. Need help to add a slot with name: 'staging' (settings to be cloned from parent)

```
resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-06-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
  sku: {
    name: sku
  }
  kind: 'linux'
}
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01' = {
  name: webAppName
  location: location
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: linuxFxVersion
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [Microsoft.Web sites/slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/slots?pivots=deployment-language-bicep&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) resource. Here a minimal example:

```
resource stagingSlot 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'staging'
  parent: yourparent
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appService.id
  }
}
```

Comment: Ran into these errors but got your solution working after making minor tweaks. Thank you!
[{"code":"NotFound","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ParentResourceNotFound\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'slotsdemo' not found.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}

Error BCP170: Expected resource name to not contain any "/" characters. Child resources with a parent resource reference (via the parent property or via nesting) must not contain a fully-qualified name.

Comment: Thank you, it worked with minor tweaks.
 name: 'staging'
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  parent: appService
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
  }
}